# System Verilog Generate - Unable to access local busses in previous loops using $size

Tags: system-verilog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twUeW.png)

I am trying to implement a OR tree using specific cell type CKOR2 in stages.
The stage is in a generate loop. I need to access the previous loops output bus width in the current loop to determine the width and define the output bus of the current stage.

I get errors on the line using $size

```
module test ( A, o );
    parameter WIDTH = 9 ;
    input [WIDTH-1:0] A;
    output o;
    localparam NUM_OR_STAGES = $clog2(WIDTH) ;
    genvar i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OR_STAGES; i=i+1) begin: OR
        localparam j=i-1;
        if ( i == 0 ) begin
            localparam width = WIDTH;
            wire [WIDTH-1:0] stgout;
            assign stgout = A;
        end 
        else begin
            localparam width = $size( OR[i-1].stgout ) ; 
            localparam width_div2 = width/2;
            localparam offset = ( width % 2); 
            wire [width_div2-1:0] stgo;
            wire [width_div2+offset-1:0] stgout;
            CKOR2 u_ckor[width_div2-1:0] ( .o(stgo), .i0(OR[i-1].stgout[width-1:width-width_div2]), .i1(OR[i-1].stgout[width-width_div2-1:width-2*width_div2]));
            if ( offset )
                assign stgout = { stgo,OR[i-1].stgout[0] };
            else 
                assign stgout = stgo;
        end
    end
    assign o = OR[NUM_OR_STAGES -1].stgout;
endmodule
```

Comment: Please post the error detail as well so that it will be easier to trace the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that each iteration of the loop the width will change based on the previous stgout[i-1] width. So, for initial input width of 9, width of stgout[0]=5, stgout[1] would be 3, stgout[2] would be 2, stgout[3] would be 1. So, current output stgout[i] is based on previous stgout[i-1].

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `stgout[0]` is declared inside an unnamed `begin/end` block, and you can't access it from outside the block. This is also a problem for the `CKOR2` port connections. Naming the blocks would not solve your problem because you would have to switch between referencing the `i==0` branch when `i` is 1, and the other branch when `i!=1`. Better to move the declarations outside the `if/else` branches. I didn't test the math, but this should get you close:

```
module test ( A, o );
    parameter WIDTH = 9 ;
    input [WIDTH-1:0] A;
    output o;
    localparam NUM_OR_STAGES = $clog2(WIDTH) ;
    genvar i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OR_STAGES; i=i+1) begin: OR
      localparam width = WIDTH*2/(i+1);
      localparam width_div2 = width/2;
      localparam offset = ( width % 2); 
      wire [width_div2+offset-1:0] stgout;
      if ( i == 0 ) begin
            assign stgout = A;
      end else begin
            wire [width_div2-1:0] stgo;
            CKOR2 u_ckor[width_div2-1:0] ( .o(stgo), .i0(OR[i-1].stgout[width-1:width-width_div2]), .i1(OR[i-1].stgout[width-width_div2-1:width-2*width_div2]));
            if ( offset )
                assign stgout = { stgo,OR[i-1].stgout[0] };
            else 
                assign stgout = stgo;
        end
    end
    assign o = OR[NUM_OR_STAGES -1].stgout;
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that each iteration of the loop the width will change based on the previous stgout[i-1] width. So, for initial input width of 9, width of stgout[0]=5, stgout[1] would be 3, stgout[2] would be 2, stgout[3] would be 1. So, current output stgout[i] is based on previous stgout[i-1].

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your diagram or code. The first iteration of your original  `for` loop declares `OR[0].stgout[WIDTH-1:0]`, so its bit-width is 9. My version has the first iteration `OR[0].stgout[width_div2+offset-1:0]` where `width_div2=9` and `offset=0`. So bit-width is also 9.

The second iteration of my loop has`width_div2=4` and `offset=1`. So bit-width of `OR[1].stgout` is 5.

Comment: Yes, there is a logic problem in my code but the problem is that each loop should have a different dimension of stgout. Input bus of width 9 should produce output bus of size (9/2=)4 +(9 % 2)1 = 5. Next loop input bus will be width 5 and produce output bus of size (5/2)2 + (5 % 2)1=3, next input bus 3 with output bus width 2, then next is input bus 2, output 1 - this is result.

Comment: That's exactly what my code does with `WIDTH*2/(i+1)` 'i' is part of the equation.